# TypeError when mocking request with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm relatively new to node and am having issues trying to mock `request` using jest.

If my file to be tested has `require('request')`, and I try to run `npm test`, I get this error:

```
FAIL  __tests__/sum-test.js (0.291s)
● sum › it adds 1 + 2 to equal 3
  - TypeError: The super constructor to `inherits` must have a prototype.
        at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:756:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js:44:6)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js:16:18)
```

Here's my package.json, if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "jesttest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^12.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.72.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `jest.unmock('request')` in your test file.

Jest will mock a fake require object when you require something in your file.In this situation, request is not the real request.So tell jext not mock request.

Comment: This worked for me. @Manu if this worked for you, please accept this as the answer.